# Using 'ambiguous' bool parameter with Series.tz_localize doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set the time zone of a DatetimeIndex object using the *ambiguous* parameter and filling it with a bool-ndarray, as described in the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html):

This doesn't seem to work, because I still get a *Cannot infer dst time* error when, for example, using *floor*:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range(start='2018-11-04', end = '2018-11-05', freq = 'min')
dates.tz_localize(tz='US/Central', ambiguous = np.ones((1441,), dtype=bool)).floor('H')


File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 963, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.tz_localize_to_utc

AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from '2018-11-04 01:00:00', try using the 'ambiguous' argument
```

However, using the *ambiguous* parameter with a non-boolean value does seems to work:

```py
dates.tz_localize(tz='US/Central', ambiguous = 'NaT').floor('H')

DatetimeIndex(['2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00', '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00',
           '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00', '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00',
           '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00', '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00',
           '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00', '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00',
           '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00', '2018-11-04 00:00:00-05:00',
           ...
           '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00', '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00',
           '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00', '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00',
           '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00', '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00',
           '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00', '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00',
           '2018-11-04 23:00:00-06:00', '2018-11-05 00:00:00-06:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns, US/Central]', length=1441, freq=None)
```

Why is this? Could you please explain how to use the bool version of the parameter?

Comment: you are getting the error because on Nov. 4, 2018 at 2:00AM central time Daylight Saving Time (DST) ended. It does not know whether 1:00am is DST or not. Trying to set everything to True might not be the best approach.

Comment: Why is trying to set everything to true not the best?

Comment: Because then it will default ambiguous times to DST which may not be the case. There are some states in the US that do not observe daylight saving time

Comment: I get your point, but that is what I want to do (as a test, in order to get rid if the *Cannot infer dst error*). P.S. - Thanks for helping!

Comment: to help with your question...it looks like it's a bug and should be fixed in the `0.24` release [pandas 0.24.0.dev0](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) they are adding the ambiguous param to `dt.floor()`